# How to access data record after ListBox selected with LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, listboxitems, livebindings

I have a TSQLDataset, Im using the livebindings to bind it to a listbox. When I click on the listbox item, I want to be able to access the other fields of data from the record, but I cannot figure out how to do it because I cannot get the dataset to the corresponding item.
I know that I could possibly take the ID Field and maybe assign it to `Selected.Tag` using live bindings but can't figure that out either, but if I could then I could have another a SQLQuery and then just return the result of the query

`SELECT * FROM Dataset WHERE ID=(Tag value)`

That would work, but I don't know how to get livebindings to set the items tag value when live bindings populates the Listbox.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out because I'm now having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to link Tag property of the ListBox with the ID of the record.

Answer (score -1):

There's a Sensor Info demo application from Embarcadero in XE5 Samples directory...

There you have `OnItemClick = lbMainItemClick` in TListBox events then you have to define the event handler:

```
procedure TfrmAboutSensors.lbMainItemClick(const Sender: TCustomListBox; const Item: TListBoxItem);
begin
  if Assigned(Item.OnClick) then
    Item.OnClick(Item);
end;
```

And then for every item on the list:

```
for LItem in LListBox do
begin
    //LItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aDetail;  // my code
    //LItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aNone;    // my code
    LItem.OnClick := ListBoxItemClick;
end;
```

Please give us callback if that helps.

Comment: This answer does not address the actual question being asked - how to determine and access the db record that is selected in the listbox.